# How to create and apply custom site template for SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-template

How to create and apply custom site template for SharePoint? I want to create a site template with minimal features to get started.

Is there any link which shows screen-shots of the templates which are by-default available in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a list of the OOTB Site Definitions with screen-shots see [SharePoint 2013 Site Templates](http://blog.cloudshare.com/2012/12/06/sharepoint-2013-site-templates/)

Before creating your own Site Definition consider if what you really need is instead a WebTemplate (The main advantages being supports updating. cloud and local availability, the main disadvantage being not supporting Feature Stapling).

For a description of both Site Definitions and WebTemplates including comparison and instructions on how to create them see MSDN article [Site Types: WebTemplates and Site Definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms434313%28v=office.14%29.aspx) (nothing changed in this area for SP2013 so the SP2010 article is still 100% relevant)

Comment: No it's not for SP2013. Avoid using 10000 as an ID for your SiteDefinition because 10000 is used for DOCMARKETPLACESITE#0 (Academic Library) in SP2013. I came across with that while trying to migrate a solution based on a 10000-template from 2010 to 2013 and it gave me an invalid-template error. I tried to add a comment on the MS-article but there is no comment-function, just a feedback-button that I used instead.