# How to create a custom application template like "Team Site", "Document Center" in SP 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Please someone help me to understand what are all the approaches to create a custom application/SharePoint template with customised functionality in SP 2013 for intranet, which is the best one?

user will select my custom template from the list (as shown in below) to create a new site. 
[image]

Comment: similar to question, https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55544/how-to-create-and-apply-custom-site-template-for-sharepoint . Kindly check the answer for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is slightly loaded and general, thus I can only give you a general answer as well.  I only know of 2 ways to create a custom site template in SharePoint on-premise:

1. Using the OOTB SharePoint feature "**Save as Template**".  This is my recommended approach as this is simple and should satisfy most requirements out there.

   - Basically you just build a site upon a OOTB Site template and add/modify all your business requirements onto the site.  Once you are done, you simply create a site template from this site which then can be used to create other sites that will have the same content and features.
   - This new template would be listed in the "Custom" tab when choosing a template to create a site.
   - There are some caveats to this depending if you have custom developed solutions, apps, etc on this template.
   - More info about this can be found [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-use-site-templates-60371b0f-00e0-4c49-a844-34759ebdd989) (SharePoint 2013 is basically the same)
2. Using Visual Studio to create a Site definition solution.  This approach provide the most flexibility and customization possible BUT

   - Requires extensive knowledge on SharePoint development.  (There are full time jobs just to be a SharePoint developer)
   - Requires a SharePoint development environment which is costly, complicated and is high maintenance.
   - More info about this can be found [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/steps-to-create-custom-site-definition-in-sharepoint-2013-using-visual-studio/)